# Reactjs show hide multiple components

Tags: reactjs

Newbie React question here on show hide functionality.

I have a state of 'show' that I set to false:

```
    this.state = {
      show: false,
    };
```

Then I use the following function to toggle

```
     toggleDiv = () => {
        const { show } = this.state;
        this.setState({ show : !show })
    }
```

And my display is

```
{this.state.show && <xxxxxx> }
```

This all works fine. However I want to apply the function it to multiple cases (similar to accordion, without the closing of other children. So I change my constructor to

```
    this.state = {
      show: [false,false,false,false,false,false]
    };
```

and this to recognise there are 6 different 'shows'.

```
{this.state.show[0] && <xxxxxx> }
{this.state.show[1] && <xxxxxx> } etc
```

But where I get stuck is how to account for them in my toggleDiv function. How do I insert the square bracket reference to the index of show (if this is my problem)?

```
    toggleDiv = () => {
        const { show } = this.state;
        this.setState({ show : !show })
    }
```

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I'd suggest you not to rely on *current* state in `setState` function, but to use the callback option to be 100% sure that you are addressing to the newest state:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({ show: !prevState.show }));
```

**How to deal with multiple elements**?

You'll have to pass the `index` of currently clicked element.

```
{yourElements.map((elem, i) => <YourElem onClick={this.toggleDiv(i)} />)}
```

and then inside your `toggleDiv` function:

```
toggleDiv = (i) => () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        const r = [...prevState.show]; // create a copy to avoid state mutation
        r[i] = !prevState.show[i];

        return {
           show: r,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks kind user but I have to admit I'm totally lost here. I am not even sure where the second piece of code is supposed to go, let alone the difference between 'youElements' and 'YourElem'. I do appreciate you having taken the time to assist me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use an array instead of a single value. In your toggle div function make a copy of the state array make necessary changes and push the entire array back up to state at the end.

This is some simplified code showing the workflow I described above

```
export default class myClass extends React.Component{
   constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { show: new Array(2).fill(false) };
   }
   //you need a index or id to use this method
   toggleDiv = (index) => {
      var clone = Object.assign( {}, this.state.show ); //ES6 Clones Object
      switch(clone[index]){
         case false:
         clone[index] = true
            break;
         case true:
            clone[index] = false
            break;
      }
      this.setState({ show: clone });
   }
   render(){
      return(
    <div>
         { this.state.show[0] && <div> First Div </div> }
         { this.state.show[1] && <div> Second Div </div> }
         { this.state.show[2] && <div> Third Div </div> }
    </div>
      )
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler, but doesn't seem to be working for me. I can set and read the array but the ToggleDiv function doesn't work, and I am not getting any errors. Am I missing a reference to the index when setting state?

I added a default case in the switch function